# Will all nodes get repaired if I run nodetool repair on 1 node?

Tags: cassandra

I have 5 nodes with replication factor 5. This means the node has a range of partitions. if I run `nodetool repair --full` on node 1, will all my nodes get repaired or will only node 1 get repaired?

Answer (score 1):

In this instance where each node holds a full copy of the data, `nodetool repair` will repair all token ranges which means that data will be synchronised across all 5 nodes. Cheers!